# Select box jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Can someone explain why this code shows me blank select box  ? When I select first box which name is "firstbox" then it should be showing info in second box which id is "komandos" but it won't showing anything...

```
<script>

jQuery(function($) {
    $("#komandos").change(function() {
        var id = $("#id").val();
        if(isNaN(id)) {return;}

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {'update_tm': '', 'id': id},
            dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){

                $("#komandos").empty();

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                {
                    $("#komandos").append('<option>'+data[i].team+'</option>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
include_once('inc/conn.php');
include_once('inc/futbolas.php');

if(isset($_GET['update_tm']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `pirma_komanda`,`antra_komanda` FROM futbolas WHERE `id` = ?");
 $query->execute(array($_GET['id']));
if($query)
{
   $query = $query->fetch();
   $rez[0]['team'] = $query['pirma_komanda'];
   $rez[1]['team'] = $query['antra_komanda'];
   echo json_encode($rez);
}

}
```

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  Is the AJAX request sent?  What is the server's response?  Are the elements appended as you expect?  Can you put in at least *some* effort to identify the problem?

Comment: Ajax shows teams perfect. But the select box is blank. It's showing no errors... When checking them like this:

ajax.php?update_tm=1&id={game_id}

Comment: Sounds like you need to step through the `success` handler in a debugger.  Have you perhaps tried that?  Debuggers are *really* useful for debugging code.

Comment: Could you add the raw result of the AJAX call to your question?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use `JSON.parse` like

```
success: function(data){

            $("#komandos").empty();
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
            {
                $("#komandos").append('<option>'+result[i].team+'</option>');
            }
        }
    });
```

See **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y3bvhxy7/)**

Comment: this is correct if your php return the json string. try to alert you response from ajax `alert(data)` what is in it also try to alert in for loop `alert(result[i].team)`

Comment: @SKRocks - JSON.parse is not the answer here. He is already setting the return type to be json so the response should already be coming back to be used as in object. If you use firebug/chrome dev tools check the network tabs to see what is actually be sent back on the call. You might not be referencing the object from the response correctly? Along those lines, What does the JSON response look like?